# Dates values displayed 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, phpmyadmin, datetime

I have imported a `csv` file into my database created in phpmyadmin using sql.

> Server version: 5.6.37 - MySQL Community Server (GPL

I have a column for dates which has a datatype of [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html). The data displayed on webpage for all the dates are as `0000-00-00`. However in the `csv` file the format is `12/2/2016`. Could any one please help how could I resolve this issue?

Comment: What are the values stored in MySQL server?

Comment: Looks like you failed to import dates properly, so the server returns the default "zero" values.

Comment: From excel convert it into yyyy-mm-dd (2016-02-12) format then try to import.

Comment: *.csv file the format is 12/2/2016.* Wrong format. You must see a lot of warnings - why does you ignore them? Use UDV to convert it to the format clear for server (YYYY-MM-DD) during import.

Answer (score 2):

Use user-defined variable for to convert the date value from `dd\mm\YYYY` format to the date/datetime datatype value during import:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
....
(field1, field2, ..., @date, ...)
SET datefield = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d\/%m\/%Y');
```